# Compile Latex Documents in Android App

Tags: java, android, c, latex

I developed an Android app, where the user can type in some data and create a .tex (latex) document of his data. Is there a way to compile these latex documents within my app, so the user gets an pdf from the latex document?

Thanks.

Comment: Your user would need a LaTeX distribution on his phone. I have no idea of the state of LaTeX distributions for Android, but most things I've seen depend on a cloud compilation service. Have a look whether one of those might suit your purposes.

Comment: See [How to install TeX on android phones?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/87520)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [MathJAX](http://www.mathjax.org/) and simply allow them to render it in the browser.